# Would a comma be needed before, after or both of the word "hopefully" in this sentence?

Tags: punctuation

In the future, I plan to learn to play several more instruments and hopefully become a member of the band.

Comment: No, it's fine as it is.

Comment: @snailboat Yeah, if he became a band member while full of hope.  You are trying to use it as an adverb.  Just because it ends in a "ly" does not mean that you must use it as an adverb.  "He swam hopefully toward shore."  That is using "hopefully" as an adverb--it is describing how he "swam".  This is not describing how he 'became'.  This is a parenthetical expression interrupting a thought. He did not 'become' a band member 'hopefully'.

Comment: @snailboat By the way, the P.E. still functions as an adverb, but not "in a hopeful manner" as is the adverb form that you wish to use. www.dictionary.com 
hopefully 
adverb
1.
in a hopeful manner: We worked hopefully and energetically, thinking we might finish first.
2.
it is hoped; if all goes well: Hopefully, we will get to the show on time.
(Notice how the second, correct use utilized a parenthetical expression.)  Straight from the dictionary, bra. (Notice that it did not and could not say "We will get hopefully to the show."--BECAUSE IT IS A PARENTHETICAL EXPRESSION, BRA.)

Answer (score 8):

'Hopefully' is being used as a parenthetical expression to interrupt a thought and not as a conjunctive adverb joining two sentences.

Since it is functioning as a parenthetical expression, you need to punctuate it with two commas.

"...and, hopefully, become a member of the band."

Comment: The alternative you suggest being 'In the future, I plan to learn to play several more instruments; hopefully, I will become a member of the band.'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes.  As a teacher of ELA, I have found that students are taught to use a conjunctive adverb to join sentences before they are taught to use them as parenthetical expressions.  When I saw this question, I appreciated how he appropriately joined sentences, wanted to enrich his writing with "hopefully", yet appeared to be confused in regards to punctuation since he already used a coordinating conjunction to join the thoughts.  I might make too many assumptions about my students' misconceptions, but I usually base them in my extensive experience. I apologize for any ambiguity.

Comment: Isn't it fine the way it is though? Does there have to be commas around it? Can't be be left alone?

Comment: @Tucker For parallelism, it is better suited as a parenthetical expression:  "to learn and become" vs "to learn and hopefully become"  An example of how you would use it adverbially while effectively maintaining parallelism would be, "to quickly learn and hopefully become"--now we are parallel.  However, since we said "to learn", we are better served using hopefully as a parenthetical expression so that it does not interfere with parallelism.

Comment: @APrejean Thank you! Yes, that makes it much clearer.

Comment: Since I don't accept the classification of such pragmatic markers as adverbs, "to quickly learn and hopefully become" isn't true parallelism any more than 'We ask you _to please start and diligently continue_ ...'.  'Hopefully' in the non-adverbial sense is equivalent to a 'comment clause', 'it is to be hoped'. One can't write 'He waited it is to be hoped for the results of the lottery'. The usages are very different.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Even if I accept what you are stating about disagreeing with the parallelism comment, it is still a parenthetical expression.  Refer to my comment above.  If we did not use commas, it would mean "in a hopeful manner".: "We worked hopefully and energetically..."  He is using hopefully here with the meaning "it is hoped", which is performed as a parenthetical expression (or Conjunctive Adverb): "Hopefully, we will get to the show on time."  He did not "become" a band member "in a hopeful manner" "He hopefully became..." It is hopeful that he will become one, "he, hopefully, became

Comment: It **is** an expression that can be deleted without ruining the grammar or altering the meaning of the matrix sentence. This does not mean that it **requires** commas (or dashes or parentheses) around it. The non-adverb usage is often easily deduced, and the commas are unnecessary. Check all the examples [here](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all#hl=all&q=%22we+will+hopefully%22) and [here](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all#hl=all&q=%22and+we+will+hopefully%22).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth did you just give me a link to two google searches as your citation?  If you said "hopefully became", it obfuscates the meaning. The parenthetical expression is the only way to clearly give the secondary meaning in this case; further, it does promote parallelism.  I honestly feel like you are just being stubborn to defend a point.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Let's go at this from a different direction.  "After our boat flipped, we swam hopefully toward shore." Can we say "After our boat flipped(; hopefully, / , hopefully / , hopefully) we swam toward shore." and have the same meaning?  Once we establish a structure and usage on use (1) and, more importantly, what we CANNOT do with use (1), we can begin analyzing the one I am promoting, use (2).

Comment: Perhaps you'll accept this, from [grammar.ccc.comnet] (http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/adverbs.htm): When the adverb does not fit into the flow of the clause, it is called a disjunct or a conjunct and **is often** set off by a comma or set of commas. A disjunct frequently acts as a kind of evaluation of the rest of the sentence. [Their terminology; my bolding] Often, not always. The links I give above have many examples of such usages not using commas. (I'm not saying that commas aren't _ever_ needed.)  Here, like rogermue, I think OP needs rephrasing.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I agree completely with what you just said.  Are you saying a disjunct adverb should not be set off by commas?  Because if you don't set it off by commas, you need rephrasing (as you just said).  That is the exact issue here.  As with the dictionary usage--it said, "Hopefully, we will get to the show on time." and not, "We will (hopefully) get (hopefully) to the show on time." because we are not 'hopefully' getting and the only way to avoid ambiguity is by adding commas.  So the real question becomes this:  Does it still need rephrasing ONCE I added the commas?

Comment: Because if it does not need rephrasing, I resolved the ambiguity in meaning by an "often-used" parenthetical expression and the whole argument is academic.

Comment: There are 667 000 Google hits for "he will hopefully become". The first thirty include twent-seven commaless and one commaed (and two bracketed) versions.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth And there are over 1,700,000 results for "it aint" in quotations with no apostrophe...

Comment: As opposed to 393 000 000 with one. Don't use 'He will hopefully become ...' without commas if you don't want to. Just don't force a pseudo-rule down everybody's throat.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You still haven't answered my question.  Does it still need rephrasing after I added commas?  If it does not, then you argument is academic since you already admitted you thought it needed rephrasing without them.  I want you to be completely honest... In your opinion, does it need to be corrected still once commas are added?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14270/discussion-between-edwin-ashworth-and-a-prejean)

Answer (score 1):

Your bare infinitive "become" is dangling in the air. One does not know where your bare infinitive belongs to - the reader has the choice of two verbs plan and learn and you make the reader try to find out how you constructed this sentence.

That is no good. I would choose the simplest and clearest formulation: 
... and I hope to become a member of the band.